# How to control state of multiple inputs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating an app wherein a user can create a set of flashcards with a term and description each. I also want the flashcards to be editable as soon as they add a flashcard. So each flashcard they add gets pushed to a variable with a controlled state. Then I created a component that returns inputs with all of the flashcard data.
this is what it would like look like:
[image]

There's no problem with that it works fine. But I want them to be editable once added. So I added an onchange to each of the inputs and did this:

```
function handleChange(event){
        const {value, name, dataset} = event.target
        const index = dataset.index
        const newFlashcardSet = [...flashcardValues]
        newFlashcardSet[index][name] = value;
        setFlashcardValues(newFlashcardSet)
    }
```

so when the user tries to type on the submitted flashcard they can edit it.

**PROBLEM**

As you can probably tell, each key keystroke calls the function, and rerenders all the data. Causing it to eat up a lot of cpu usage, even though it is not noticeable at first, but as soon as you add more flashcards, you would definetly notice the slow performance, because it rerenders all the data every keystroke. What is the best way to go around this?

Comment: *as soon as you add more flashcards, you would definetly notice the slow performance* Really, did you try it? I doubt it's a problem - modern computers can handle thousands or hundreds of thousands of pieces of data in an instant in many cases. Also, don't mutate state in React like you're doing, it can cause problems

Comment: Could try using some debouncing strategies.you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-debounce-input or may be define your own debouncing logic

Comment: @user700284 what does it do? could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: @CloydAbad Basically your code would wait for a certain time before the onchange handlers are executed. So when you continuosly type values into an input field, not all keystrokes would execute your onchange handler

Comment: @user700284 it defeats the whole purpose, it will make my app look even slower.

Comment: No..it would not..the delay normally would be in milliseconds and the end user would not notice the delay.Anyway it was just a suggestion from my side. Please feel free to explore other options too

Comment: 1. use debounced handler. link https://docs-lodash.com/v4/debounce/. You can implement your own debounce as well.          

2. QUESTION : Are you storing all the data as array of objects or similar structure? 
ex: [ {}, {}, {}]

Comment: @SanchitKumar yes im storing all of them in a single array. thats why im asking for any better solution, because all of the data gets overwritten everytime the state changes, even the ones that weren't changed, still got overwritten.